# How to running ajax from php 5.2 into php 5.4

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem with ajax script.
I create ajax script in php 5.2 the function succes. 
but when i try in php 5.4 the function not running. 
Anyone can help me..

Here's My Script.

```
<script> function makeAjaxCall()
{ 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "post", 
        data: $('#form1').serialize(), 
        url: "http://192.168.0.77/IWOS_CI/trans_invent_controller/getCode", 
        cache: false,   
        success: function(json){        
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json); 
        var r = obj['STATUS'];
        } 
        });
} 
</script>
<form name="form1" id="form1">
<input type="text" id="kode_trans_invent" name="kode_trans_invent">
</form>
```

And here my php function from controller.

```
public function getCode()   
    { 
    $query      = $this->db->query("SELECT count(*) + 1 as count FROM TB_TRANS_INVENT WHERE KODE_TRANS_INVENT ='". mysql_escape_string($_POST['kode_trans_invent']) ."'");
    $queryData  = $query->row_array();
    $phpVar     = array( "STATUS" => $queryData['count']); 
    echo json_encode ($phpVar) ;    
    }
```

Thanks for the attention..

Comment: looks like cross domian issue....

Comment: also `mysql_escape_string` is deprecated make sure you don't use it http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in the code you've shown explains why it's not working now. But what *I'd* do (assuming this problem is actually caused by the PHP version migration) is making sure I'm not using any deprecated functions that could be causing PHP to throw an `E_DEPRECATED` error that halts the execution. As you're migrating from PHP 5.2 to 5.4, check in these logs:

[Deprecated features in PHP 5.3.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php) and
[Deprecated features in PHP 5.4.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.deprecated.php).

Comment: Chances are that the error output is showing up in the JSON, causing parsing to fail.